# RuntimeException in Uber application: Font asset not found sans-serif

Tags: applications, samsung, crashes, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+, uber

I've got my uber application completely not working for the last week. 
The moment I choose the target address, the applications freezes for 1 sec and then it crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Font asset not found sans-serif
```

I have tried:

- Delete application and install it back
- Delete its cache
- Wipe all the cache through the boot menu
- Reset all user settings to default

None of these helped. The only thing that I have in my mind its hard reset. But it's very undesirable scenario cause I have so much data and settings configured on my phone that It will take me months to return it back. Is there other way around to fix that problem?

```
Device: Samsung Galaxy S6 Plus Edge 
OS: Android 7.0
```

Full exception stack trace:

[image: java.lang.RuntimeException]

Comment: Have you contacted Uber's support?

Comment: I have sent error report for several times. I didn't get any response, though.

Comment: Can you change the system font to something else and test ?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the font. I even tried to find more fonts and to apply them. This doesn't help.

Comment: Have you done any system modification on this phone (rooting, Xposed, or similar?)

Comment: No, nothing from that. Haven't even installed software from unknown sources.